# React map() - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'categories' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

The variable appStructure will be shown as below image.

When I console.log(category),
It shows - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'categories' of undefined

I am not sure if the reason is the appStructure value is [] when useEffect run for the first time.

```
const [structure, setstructure] = useState([]);
const [previewOption, setpreviewOption] = useState([])

useEffect(() =>{

    if(structure){
        structure.structure.categories.map(category =>{
            console.log(category)
        })
   }
},[structure])
```

Comment: Initial state is an empty array, it won't have a `structure` property (i.e. `appStructure.structure` is undefined) to access a `categories` property of.

Comment: so "if(appStructure)" is useless to prevent this situation?

Comment: Try optional chaining if that supports in your application.  `appStructure?.structure?.categories?.map`

Comment: (1) Change initial state type to match what it gets populated by, object vs. array, and (2) you need to check the existence of every property depth you access, either like `appStructure.structure && appStructure.structure.categories && appStructure.structure.categories.map(...` or use optional chaining if supported.

Answer (score 0):

The `useEffect` gets fired when the component gets mounted and when any of the values in its dependency array changes. So when the component mounts, the value for `appStructure` is an empty array, as it's declared like `const [appStructure, setAppStructure] = useState([]);`. Since it's not null or undefined, it passes the `if` in your hook and therefore will not find the property `structure` throwing the error you are facing.

You can solve this by changing your `if` sentence to:

```
if(appStructure.structure)
```

Assuming you will always have `categories` inside that object.

Answer (score 0):

Your `appStructure` looks like an object, but you initialise the state as an empty array. Try setting it to `null` instead:

```js
const [appStructure, setAppStructure] = useState(null);
```

Depending on what your system will or might return, you could add more checks in the if statement to make sure all objects are present before running the `map()`:

```js
if(appStructure && appStructure.structure && appStructure.structure.categories) {
  // Run map()
}
```